# Map and filter an object using Ramda

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

I'm learning [`Ramda`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) and I'm a little confused how to build this `lodash` chain below using `Ramda`. `Ramda` returns functions for it's operations instead of actual values, and this seems to be the focal point of functional programming, however in this example I have a second parameter `localRegex` that isn't a primary argument. It seems that it wouldn't be possible to get this to be completely duplicated without wrapping the `Ramda` function and using `.apply()` or `.call()` to propagate the wrapped function arguments to the `Ramda` function, which seems more complicated then using `lodash`.

```
var _ = require("lodash")
var R = require("ramda")

var localRegex = /^.\.\/|^.\/|^\//

function getRecursiveDeps(deps, localRegex){
  return _.chain(deps)
    .map(function(dep){
      return dep.source.value
    })
    .filter(function(dep){
      return dep.match(localRegex)
    })
    .value()
}

var items = [
  {
    "source": {
      "value": "./foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "source": {
      "value": "bar"
    }
  }
]

console.log(getRecursiveDeps(items, localRegex))
```

Here's what I've got and its not working.

```
var getRecursiveDeps = R.chain(
  R.map(function(dependency){
    return dependency.source.value
  }),
  R.filter(function(value){
    return value.match(localRegex)
  })
)
```

Is there a way to have `Ramda` use a main variable for chaining and also pass down `localRegex`? Is there a way to duplicate the `getRecursiveDeps` that uses `lodash` in `Ramda`?

There's a lot of talk about how `Ramda` is functional and `underscore` and `lodash` aren't. But in this case the `getRecursiveDeps` is a function that returns a value from `lodash`. When you create functions like this from `lodash` or `underscore` the result is the same, there's just more work when it comes to wrapping it, in this case what would be the perk using `Ramda` over `Lodash`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`R.chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) does something completely different from `_.chain`. Its type, according to the current documentation, is `(a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`, though its actual type is more general. Think of it as a "flat-map" function.

What you actually want here is [`R.compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) or its left-to-right equivalent [`R.pipe`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe).

If the goal of the function is to find local dependencies, it seems appropriate to me to embed the pattern in the function. I would thus write:

```
// getLocalDeps :: [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> [String]
const getLocalDeps =
R.pipe(R.map(R.path(['source', 'value'])),
       R.filter(R.test(/^[.]{0,2}[/]/)));

getLocalDeps(items);  // => ['./foo']
```

I'm a bit confused by the name `getRecursiveDeps` as the function isn't recursive. `getLocalDeps` seems more appropriate.

---

If you'd like to parameterize the pattern, I suggest breaking `getLocalDeps` into smaller pieces:

```
// isLocal :: String -> Boolean
const isLocal = R.test(/^[.]{0,2}[/]/);

// getDeps :: [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> [String]
const getDeps = R.map(R.path(['source', 'value']));

// getLocalDeps :: [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> [String]
const getLocalDeps = R.pipe(getDeps, R.filter(isLocal));
```

You could then define other functions in terms of these building blocks:

```
// getNonLocalDeps :: [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> [String]
const getNonLocalDeps = R.pipe(getDeps, R.reject(isLocal));

// getLocalJsonDeps :: [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> [String]
const getLocalJsonDeps = R.pipe(getLocalDeps, R.filter(R.test(/[.]json$/)));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! This function is an intermediary that feeds the more elaborate `recursiveDeps` function I have in my code more local dependancies and strip out modules that don't need to be iterated over.

Comment: Would there be any way to provide the secondary argument using Ramda? Or am I pretty stuck having to wrap it in a function when the argument is more general?

Comment: I've added to my answer an approach to parameterizing the second argument.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this, points-free and preserving your existing API is like this:

```
// getLocalDeps :: [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> RegExp -> [String]
const getLocalDeps =  R.useWith(
  R.flip(R.call),
  R.map(R.path(['source', 'value'])),
  R.pipe(R.unary(R.test), R.filter)
);

localDeps(items, localRegex); //=> ["./foo"]
```

The last line of the function feels a bit unfortunate to me, and this question has caused me to [open an issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1318) about reverting some recent changes to the library.  There are several variants that could be used:

```
// ...
R.pipe(regex => item => R.test(regex, item), R.filter)
//...
```

or

```
// ...
regex => R.filter(R.test(regex))
//...
```

But before a recent change to Ramda, it would have been simply

```
// ...
R.pipe(R.test, R.filter)
//...
```

---

One thing, though, is that Ramda tries hard to keep parameters in a logical order: with those less likely to change coming before those more likely to change.  With that in mind, I would prefer something like this:

```
// getLocalDeps :: RegExp -> [{ source :: { value :: String }}] -> [String]
var getLocalDeps2 =  R.useWith(
  R.call,
  R.pipe(R.unary(R.test), R.filter),
  R.map(R.path(['source', 'value']))
);

localDeps2(localRegex, items); //=> ["./foo"]
```

And that feels cleaner still.  Moreover, it lets you predefine the function and use it separately:

```
myDeps = localDeps2(localRegex);
myDeps(items); //=> ["./foo"]
```

And that is a good part of what Ramda is about.